# How do I compare date columns with an different number of rows?

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

I am trying to make an SSRS report. The report is mostly just a simple join between two tables. However, there are four date columns that track clock ins and outs from two different systems (two columns from Table1 and one column that I split into ins and outs from Table2). I need to make comparisons on these date columns with one another. These columns can have multiple ins and outs each day.

For example, if there was a clock in on one system, there should be another clock in on the second system within the hour. My issue lies in that when there's differing amount of clocks, I end up with hard to compare results since the ins and outs from one system aren't going to line up quite the same.

Table1 (badge, clockIn, clockOut)

```
(12345, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 16:30:00.000'),
(34567, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 17:00:00.000'),
(45678, '2021-09-01 07:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 13:17:00.000'),
(45678, '2021-09-01 12:59:00.000', '2021-09-01 20:34:00.000'),
(67890, '2021-09-01 10:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 18:21:00.000'),
```

Table 2 (Badge, clockTime, Reason)

```
(12345, '2021-09-01 07:45:00.000', 'In'),
(12345, '2021-09-01 12:00:00.000', 'Out'),
(12345, '2021-09-01 12:41:00.000', 'In'),
(34567, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', 'In'),
(45678, '2021-09-01 07:00:00.000', 'In'),
(45678, '2021-09-01 12:59:00.000', 'Out'),
(67890, '2021-09-01 10:00:00.000', 'In'),
```

So when I join them it might look like:

```
12345, 2021-09-01 8:00:00, 2021-09-01 11:30:00, 2021-09-01 07:45:00, 2021-09-01 12:00:00
12345, 2021-09-01 8:00:00, 2021-09-01 11:30:00, 2021-09-01 12:41:00, 2021-09-01 12:00:00
```

My goal is to have an additional column that flags exceptions based on the times. One exception might be if Table2 doesn't have a clock within an hour of a Table1 entry. With the rows as they are, this would work fine for Row1, but would be an exception on row 2, even though it doesn't need to be since there was already a clock accounted for.

How can I join/display my data or process the exceptions so that they work in situations like this? Is it better solved in my query or my report?

Apologies ahead of time if I've done a bad job of explaining or left something out. I'm a bit frazzled.

Comment: These problems are, almost without exception, easier to resolve in your dataset query. Only in instances where the datasets are from disparate systems with not way to join them in the query should you think about doing this kind of thing in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EXISTS` and `DATEDIFF` to find problems, with different `CASE` expressions to find different problems (if you're ok with multiple columns) or one big `CASE` expression to find all the problems if you need it in one column. Here is your data (modified the ClockTime for 67890 to 12:00:00 as you didn't have any 1 hour exceptions).

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Badge VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ClockIn DATETIME NOT NULL, ClockOut DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES
    (12345, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 16:30:00.000'),
    (34567, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 17:00:00.000'),
    (45678, '2021-09-01 07:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 13:17:00.000'),
    (45678, '2021-09-01 12:59:00.000', '2021-09-01 20:34:00.000'),
    (67890, '2021-09-01 10:00:00.000', '2021-09-01 18:21:00.000')

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (Badge VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, ClockTime DATETIME NOT NULL, Reason VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @t2
VALUES
    (12345, '2021-09-01 07:45:00.000', 'In'),
    (12345, '2021-09-01 12:00:00.000', 'Out'),
    (12345, '2021-09-01 12:41:00.000', 'In'),
    (34567, '2021-09-01 08:00:00.000', 'In'),
    (45678, '2021-09-01 07:00:00.000', 'In'),
    (45678, '2021-09-01 12:59:00.000', 'Out'),
    (67890, '2021-09-01 12:00:00.000', 'In')

SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.Badge,
    t1.ClockIn,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM @t2 t2
                    WHERE ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t1.ClockIn,t2.ClockTime) < 60))
                        AND t2.Badge = t1.Badge
                        AND YEAR(t2.ClockTime) * 100 + MONTH(t2.ClockTime) + DAY(t2.ClockTime) 
                            = YEAR(t1.ClockIn) * 100 + MONTH(t1.ClockIn)+ DAY(t1.ClockIn))
    THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'NoClock' END AS Exception
FROM @t1 t1
```

| Badge | ClockIn | Exception |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-09-01 08:00:00.000 | Ok |
| 34567 | 2021-09-01 08:00:00.000 | Ok |
| 45678 | 2021-09-01 07:00:00.000 | Ok |
| 45678 | 2021-09-01 12:59:00.000 | Ok |
| 67890 | 2021-09-01 10:00:00.000 | NoClock |